# validate telephone with angular js form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to validate telephone number with angular pattern and accept 
only the below phone number formates.

1. xx-xxxx-xxxx
2. xx xxxx xxxx
3. xx.xxxx.xxxx
4. xxxxxxxxxx
5. +44xxxxxxxxxx
6. 0044xxxxxxxxxx

can you please help to make pattern for validation in angular JavaScript.

Comment: i don't have to use mask thats why i am raised this question i have to validate with ng-pattern

Comment: Regex is your best fried: `/^((\+44|0044)?\d{10}|\d{2} \d{4} \d{4}|\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{4}|\d{2}\.\d{4}\.\d{4})$/`. I would highly recommend learning regex for validation.

Comment: Thanks Ron Daton and also many thanks for your great suggestion.